Uniform equicontinuity of $(f_n)_{n\geq1}\subset C[0,1)$ is characterized by its uniform limit?
Here is a fact:

Let $f\in C[0,1)$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $f$ is a restriciton of a continuous function $F\in C[0,1]$ (here $F$ is surely uniformly continuous, since $[0,1]$ is compact).

And I think an easy analogue of this (to sequence of functions), can be

Let $(f_n)_{n\geq1}\subseteq C[0,1)$ be a sequence of uniformly continuous functions with uniform limit $f$; that is, $\sup_{[0,1)}|f_n-f|\to0(\text{ as }n\to\infty)$. Then it is uniformly equicontinuous if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$.

I have tried:
"Only If part": $\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall n\geq1\ \forall x, y\in[0,1): |x-y|<\delta\implies\ |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\varepsilon$. Let $n\to\infty$ and we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\varepsilon$. Therefore, $f$ is uniformly continuous.
"If part": $\forall\varepsilon>0 \ \exists N_\varepsilon\ \forall n>N_\varepsilon: \sup|f_n-f|<\varepsilon$. Then take $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon,N_\varepsilon)$ for the uniformly equicontinuous family $\{f_1,\ldots,f_{N_\varepsilon}\}$, with respect to $\varepsilon$. Now $\forall j>N_\varepsilon$,$\forall x,y\in[0,1)$, with $|x-y|<\delta$:
$$ |f_j(x)-f_j(y)|\leq|f_j(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f_j(y)|\leq 2\sup|f_j-f|+|f(x)-f(y)|<3\varepsilon. $$
And hence, we find $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon,N_\varepsilon)$ that depends on $\varepsilon$ only. This means the uniform equicontinuity. QED

Is my proof right? I was thinking whether $\delta$ depends not only on $\varepsilon$.

For the if part you might want to add $f$ to the family $\{f_1,\ldots,f_{N_\varepsilon}\}$ so that you indeed have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \varepsilon$, but otherwise I'd say your proof is correct and you've done a good job.
